# Monitoring Reference Counts in ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am a little confused about where to use strong and where to use weak. Are there any tools to monitor reference counts in ios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add to the other comments, while *strong reference cycles* (previously known as *retain cycles*) are important to understand, they're relatively uncommon unless you're passing around pointers to parent objects to their children. If you're doing that sort of thing, you should make sure you understand the discussion of strong reference cycles (a.k.a. retain cycles) as outlined in some Apple docs, specifically [Acquire Basic Programming Skills](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/BasicTasks/AcquireBasicProgrammingSkills/AcquireBasicSkills/AcquireBasicSkills.html), [Advance Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html), and [Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). As a practical matter, the common example of retain cycles would be if you are passing pointers to parent controllers to a child controllers. In these cases, should generally make these pointers `weak`, otherwise `strong` is generally pretty safe.

The other common situation for weak references is IBOutlets for controls in a NIB or Storyboard, which should also generally be `weak`. (If you make the outlets by control dragging them from Interface Builder to your header file, it will take care of making them `weak` for you.) Anyway, I'll quote from the [Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html), which says:

> Outlets should generally be weak, except for those from File’s Owner
>   to top-level objects in a nib file (or, in iOS, a storyboard scene)
>   which should be strong. Outlets that you create should will therefore
>   typically be weak by default, because:
>
> - Outlets that you create to, for example, subviews of a view controller’s view or a window controller’s window, are arbitrary
>     references between objects that do not imply ownership.
> - The strong outlets are frequently specified by framework classes (for example, UIViewController’s view outlet, or NSWindowController’s
>     window outlet).

Comment: Looks like there haven't tools to monitor reference counter. Can you tell me which object/view controller or something else will be auto-retain by apple ? thank you !

Comment: Yes, the retainCount method is not available in ARC (but since you're not retaining and releasing manually, it's not really that necessary any more). Examples of things that are retained by iOS would including things like view controllers that are added to the view controller hierarchy via `pushViewController` or `presentViewController`, using `addSubview` to add a subview or control to a `UIView`, or when you add something to a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

Strong reference is used when you want the class to keep ownership to an object and hence prevent the object from being deallocated until the class doesn't need it anymore. It is usually used for objects that cannot be cheaply reproduced (e.g. data downloaded from the server) or things that are crucial during the operation of the class.

Weak reference is used when you need a reference to the object. The object will be gone if it is deallocated by its owner. This is usually used to for cycle referencing without worrying about the object not deallocated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should put this in a separate question or not but I'll just ask here: if I put in only strong references in my application, even in places where I am supposed to put weak references, would the only downside be a slowing of performance and more memory used? Sorry if I asked the question in the wrong place.

Comment: @qegal If you create retain cycles, you will waste memory because retain cycle objects can never be deallocated.  Other than that there is no difference.  You will not notice anything performance wise no matter what you do.

Comment: @borrrden: I think that he will notice that when he receives a memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't have to use weak except to avoid a retain cycle.  That is, as long as you don't have two objects with strong references to each other you will be fine.